# I use fviz_eig and try to change font size and type of percentage label, but I got some error

Tags: r, plot, pca, variance

I use `fviz_eig` to generate the plot of explained variance with customized size and font type of label using the following code:

```
library(factoextra)
library(FactoMineR)

stress.m_pca <- PCA(stress.m, scale.unit = TRUE, ncp = 8, graph = FALSE)
stress.m_pca2 <- prcomp(stress.m, scale. = TRUE)

fviz_eig(stress.m_pca, addlabel = F, ncp = 8) +
geom_text(label = paste(round((stress.m_pca2$sdev^2/sum(stress.m_pca2$sdev^2)*100),2),"%"),
            vjust= -0.6,
            hjust = 0.3,
            size = 8,
            family = "Times New Roman")
```

but I got the error like the attached picture and I have no idea to fix it:

[image: My result]

Suggestions or the code to resolve this error

Comment: Please make your code reproducible by providing `stress.m` in `dput()` format. Please visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Why are you mixing `PCA` with `prcomp`? Only `prcomp` is sufficient.

Comment: "I have no idea how to fix it":  a tip for the future - the error clearly points to a problem with your `label`.  So print it.  What is its length?  It needs to be of length `1` or `8`, but it isn't.  Work out why not.  Adapt your code to fix the problem.  As a complete guess, I'm going to say that the output from `stress.m_pca` is of length `8`, but the length of the output from `stress.m_pca2` isn't.  Hence the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided any data, I am using a default data available with `factoextra`. The following code works perfectly for me

```
library(factoextra)

data(decathlon2)
decathlon2.active <- decathlon2[1:23, 1:10]

res.pca <- prcomp(decathlon2.active, scale = TRUE)

fviz_eig(res.pca, addlabels = F) +
  geom_text(label = paste0(round(res.pca$sdev^2/sum(res.pca$sdev^2)*100,2),"%"), 
            vjust=-0.6, hjust = 0.3, family="serif", size = 5) +
  theme(text=element_text(family = "serif", size=15))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's also worked for my other dataset, but for this one, it causes the error
I have no idea what happens to this dataset

Comment: @AOT Without your original data it is very hard to help you out.